# Problem about inconsistent DLL linkage example in Microsoft documentation

Tags: c++

Recently, I ran into inconsistent linkage warning, and found two examples in Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-1-c4273?view=msvc-170)

The 1<sup>st</sup> example is clear; however, I cannot understand why would the 2<sup>nd</sup> would trigger inconsistent DLL linkage:

```
// C4273_b.cpp
// compile with: /W1 /clr /c
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" int printf_s(const char *, ...);   // C4273
```

Comment: perhaps try finding the actual declaration of `printf_s` in system headers.

Comment: There is a potential calling convention mismatch.  printf_s() uses `__cdecl`, the default for functions compiled with /clr in effect is `__clrcall`.  The prototype declaration in stdio.h avoids this, I'd assume this doc is based on an old version of the C++ compiler.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I forgot to mention that printf_s in system header is quite similar to that in this example, as shown [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)

Comment: @HansPassant It should be calling convention mismatch. Otherwise, I could not figure out why it would issue a warning.